# Some problem about the property of the MST generated by kruskal algorithm

Tags: algorithm

It has been proved that the ST generated by kruskal algorithm is a MST. We can call it ST1.
Now the question is: Prove that there is no other ST, maximum weighted edge of which is smaller than the maximum weighted edge in ST1.

Comment: Is your question: "Prove that there is no other ST, maximum weighted edge of which is smaler than the the maximum weighted edge in ST1." ?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean...i'm sorry for my poor description.

Comment: I did post an answer based on your comment, but you should consider rephrasing your question to have a clear problem statement. As it currently stands, it may be rather difficult for many users to decipher what your exact question is.

Comment: OK, I'll read your answer carefully and rephrase my statement right now. It is my first time to ask question on this online community. Sincere thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof by contradiction may help prove this claim.

In an MST of `N` nodes, each of the `(N-1)` edges serves the purpose of connecting two subtrees. Assume that there exists two subtrees `A` and `B`, and the edge `E` between them has the largest weight in ST1. This edge `E` is essential, as it connects the subtrees `A` and `B`. Without `E`, we could not connect `A` and `B`. (unless there exists another edge which can do the same)

Now, in order to try and find a contradiction to your claim, let's assume that there existed another edge `F` between subtrees `A` and `B`, and let's say that `F` has a smaller weight. Then, we would not need to use `E` and we can connect `A` and `B` with a smaller cost.

However, if we did have such an edge `F`, then the priority queue of edges, which is used in Kruskal's algorithm, would pop that edge `F`, before `E` was popped. (i.e., the edges would be stored in a min-heap, and would be popped in increasing order of weight) As `E` was the first edge to be popped between the nodes included in `A` and `B` (i.e., the first one that is able to connect subtrees `A` and `B`) we can state that no such edge `F` exists, and `E` is the edge with the smallest weight that can connect subtrees `A` and `B`. No matter how you construct a spanning tree, when you try to connect the subtrees `A` and `B`, there isn't any edge `F` with a smaller weight that you can use. So, to have a spanning tree, which has to include all `N` nodes, you have to use that edge `E`.